# Auto silence based on geo location - android

Tags: geolocation

I’m trying to get my kids android devices to be on do not disturb mode when they’re at school. 
Schedule based works fine but also effective on holidays which is I wanted. 
Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question for grammar as it currently doesn't make sense. We can't migrate it to the correct site in its current condition.

Comment: Try IFTTT (if this, then that)

Answer (score 2):

There is a free app called IFTTT (If This Then That). It lets you set up a trigger and an action that happens when the trigger fires. You could set the school as a geofence trigger, and "Set to do not disturb" as the action. Unfortunately, this app on its own will not stop them from simply turning off 'Do not disturb' manually. You will need some other parental control that stops them from messing with the settings.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using an app like `Tasker`?
Here's a [reddit link](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/75zlpw/turn_onoff_do_not_disturb_based_on_location/) with a possible solution for your query.